# Elastic search query for getting array of values

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

Hi have written a query for getting the avg of values at a position in Elastic search
elastic search payload : **"userData": [ { "sub":1234, "value":678,"condition" :"A" },{ "sub":1234, "value":678,"condition" :"B" }]**

```
{ 
  "aggs": { 
    "student_data": { 
      "date_histogram": { 
        "field":"@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval":"minute"
      },
      "aggs": { 
        "user_avg": { 
          "avg": { 
            "field":"value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to get the array of elements of which the avg value is returned.
For example, if the avg of values on the basis of condition 'A' is 42 with values as  {20,10,40,60,80}

In the output needed a field which can provide an array of [20,10,40,60,80]

Comment: I can help you with a bit more clarity

Comment: Unfortunately, your example doesn't make your problem clearer (the average of the array [20,10,40,60,8] is 240?). Also, you can remove the filter by term from your aggregation, as you are already filtering in your query

Comment: @glenacota I have updated my query please have a look and I want the array of elements of which avg is being calculated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can obtain an array formatted like `[20, 10, 40, 60, 80]` in the response of a query. I can't think of a way to obtain it by using aggregations or scripted fields. Nevertheless, you can easily (1) get that information from the same query that specifies the aggregations and the filter logic; then, (2) post-process the query response to collect all the `value`'s values used to calculate the average, by formatting format them in the way you prefer. How you post-process your response depends on the client/script you are using to send queries to Elasticsearch.

For example, you can output the values used to calculate the average as query hits.

```
{
  "size": 100,           <-- adjust this upper limit to your use case 
  "_source": "value",    <-- include only the `value` field in the response
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "condition": "A"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "user_avg": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can output the values used to calculate the average in a more compact way, by using terms aggregations.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": "value",
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "condition": "A"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "value",
        "size": 100 .       <-- adjust this upper limit to your use case 
      }
    },
    "user_avg": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of the latter will be something like:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "array_of_values" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 50,
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : 60,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 100,
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "user_avg" : {
      "value" : 65.0
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem which I'm facing is that when I do as you say I get all the average of all the values whether it is related to condition A or condition B. Moreover, The bucket consists of values related to condition A as well as condition B

Comment: Are you sure about this? This is not what I would expect from that query, and it is not what I get from my tests. The aggregations operate on the data returned by the specified query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure about it. The original query consists of another match query with range query also

Comment: I guess we need to see your original query, then

Comment: Your new query, as well as your comments above, are pretty different than your original problem (which was how to display the array of values used to calculate the average). Although my answer was referring to your original question, it can still be adapted to your updates. To demonstrate it, and to make sure that we are on the same page, I created this gist trying to accomodate your recent updates: https://gist.github.com/glenacota/47a0f9a563c4028032c0debbc1d557df

Comment: the payload is a bit different which you provided in the above comment,
The payload is [{
 "conditionType": "ABCD",
 "@timestamp": "2020-01-15",
 "userData": [{
  "sub": 1234,
  "value": 678,
  "condition": "A"
 }, {
  "sub": 1234,
  "value": 400,
  "condition": "B"
 }]
}, {
 "conditionType": "ABCD",
 "@timestamp": "2020-01-15",
 "userData": [{
  "sub": 1234,
  "value": 600,
  "condition": "A"
 }, {
  "sub": 1234,
  "value": 121,
  "condition": "B"
 }]
}]

And the above query still doesn't work for me

Comment: Ok, I see. The problem is in the mapping of your `userData` field, which I imagine is not a `nested` datatype. If this is the case, filtering by the value of `userData.condition` might return you unexpected results, because of the way non-nested array of objects are processed by Elasticsearch. Please read the relevant documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html , which also offers an explanation of the issue I'm talking about in this comment.